# Foundation 5 The expanded topbar menu remains visible when clicking the browser "back" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

> I just looked at the Foundation site, and this appears to be the default behavior. It seems strange. Clicking the browser back button should load the previous page but, it opens menu dropdown.
>   How can I hide that menu drop down? And it should show the previous page.

Thanks

Comment: wat page are u talking about?foundation site works fine for me

Comment: @SaiRamSudheer this is the Link for issue [click here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) open this and resize your browser window to less than 720 and click on topbar menu and got to any link and then click browser back button - it should open previous page without showing drop down menu

Comment: works fine in my browser chrome. just check it once again and raise an issue if you think its a bug https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues?labels=top+bar&page=1&state=open